Decoding Byte to String is adding additional characters "\"
I am trying to convert a bytes field to str. I tried the following code. Not sure, why it is adding an extra char before and after each key and value.
print(event_json)
print(type(event_json))
event_json_nobytes = event_json.decode('utf-8')
event_obj = json.dumps(event_json_nobytes, indent=2)
print(event_obj)
print(type(event_json_nobytes))

output:
b'{"specversion": "1.0", "id": "xxxxyy", "source": "campaign", "type": "clientfed", "datacontenttype": "H8908", "time": "2024-01-27T11:51:19.288Z", "data": {"clientIdentifier": "H7508", "portfolioIdentifier": "H8908"}}'

<class 'bytes'>

"{\"specversion\": \"1.0\", \"id\": \"xxxxyy\", \"source\": \"campaign\", \"type\": \"clientfed\", \"datacontenttype\": \"H8908\", \"time\": \"2024-01-27T11:51:19.288Z\", \"data\": {\"clientIdentifier\": \"H7508\", \"portfolioIdentifier\": \"H8908\"}}"

<class 'str'>

Any lead in this regard will be really helpful. Thank you.
P.S. - I got the event_json field from a cloudevents output.

json.dumps encodes as JSON, and therefor the "already contained in your input data, need to be escaped ...

The issue you're experiencing is because you are calling json.dumps on a string that is already a JSON-encoded string.

What are you trying to do?  You have a JSONified bytes-string that is then converted to a string, which is now a JSONified string.  Passing it through dumps JSONifies the already-JSONified string again.  Did you perhaps what to do: json.dumps(json.loads(event_json_nobytes), indent=2) to get a prettier version?

Thanks for your inputs, I was not aware json.dumps converts the string to json encoded string.  The type parameter also says it as a string

json.dumps is for converting native Python objects, typically dicts or lists, into a JSON formatted string. Your input (event_json_nobytes) is already a string. So you're encoding a Python string into a string that expresses a string in JSON format. And the result you see is the correct way to express a string in a JSON string.

@deceze I don't think the closing is correct, since the linked question is about the repr of string in the REPL, and this one is about huh...being confused about what are json and str in python ? :-D

one more follow up question - I tried to write the data in event_json_nobytes into an output file. The out file looks like below:-

Is it not a problem?

It's a problem. I imagine you tried to use json.dump() , which is not correct (for the same reason).
You need to use the "normal" way :
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f :
f.write(event_json_nobytes)

Thank you again for clarifying all queries instantly.

@C4stor Fair enough, added a more apropos dupe.

print(event_json)
print(type(event_json))
event_json_nobytes = event_json.decode('utf-8')

At this point, event_json_nobytes is a string, and your mission is done if you just want to go from bytes to str.
Now, if your goal is to reformat this string, you first need to load it before re-dumping it indented :
event_obj = json.dumps(json.loads(event_json_nobytes), indent=2)

